# How do I query transactions receipts from the mirror using SDK?

Tags: javascript, hedera-hashgraph

I've got this code.

```
const client = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(operatorId, operatorKey)
const recipt = new TransactionReceiptQuery()
    .setTransactionId(transactionId)
    .execute(client)
```

Hoping that TreansactionReceiptQuery will use the mirror node. Unfortunately not. How do i get it to use the mirror node through the sdk?